# How to get max status as a column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I want to create a column that shows whether it is the max `order_status` as TRUE or FALSE based on `created_at`.

Is there a way to achieve this without a subquery in Snowflake?

[image]
Here is my example data:

```
    WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-19 11:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'pending' AS status, '2021-05-19 12:00:00'::timestamp AS created_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'successful' AS status, '2021-05-20 18:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cased row_number could work

```
SELECT id, status, created_at
, CASE 
  WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created_at DESC) 
  THEN 'TRUE' 
  ELSE 'FALSE'
  END is_final_order_status
FROM t1
```

Comment: Removing the case statement might make it simpler and faster. select * ,1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created_at DESC) is_final_order_status from t1

Comment: @AdrianWhite But would it look good in Snowflake?

Comment: “Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.” - some smart peep once said this

Comment: "The man of science is a poor philosopher."

Answer (score 2):

Using windowed MAX:

```
WITH t1(id, status, created_at) AS (
  SELECT 'A', 'created', '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'created', '2021-05-19 11:30:00'::timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'pending', '2021-05-19 12:00:00'::timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'successful', '2021-05-20 18:30:00'::timestamp AS created_at
)
SELECT *, created_at = MAX(created_at) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS is_final_order_status
FROM t1;
```

Output:

[image]